# Taylor series expansion approximation

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, fourier-series, gradient-descent

I am reading this: 
[image]

My question is how to get the first formula "has an error of order of $O(h)$", and the second formula "has error terms on order of $O(h^2)$".

I tried the taylor series expansion for the first case (could someone let me know if it is correct my expansion):

$f(x+h) = f(x) +\frac{f^{'}(x)}{1!}(x+h-x) + \frac{f^{''}(x)}{2!}(x+h-x)^2 + ...$, so I then subtract f(x) from both sides and then divides both sides by h, but my expression becomes this:

$\frac{f(x+h) -f(x)}{h} = \frac{f^{'}(x)}{1!} + \frac{f^{''}(x)}{2!}h + ...  $ , so how is this being order of $O(h)$?

similarly how is the second formula being order of $O(h^2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the order of the error for the derivative is the expansion *minus* the derivative. Thus, in your line for $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, when you subtract $f'(x)$ from your right hand side, you get all terms having a factor of $h$. Since the terms with higher powers of $h$ go to $0$ faster than those with lower powers, the order becomes the one with the lowest power of $h$, i.e., $\frac{f''(x)h}{2}$, which has a power of $1$ for the $h$, so it's an $O(h)$ error term.

In general, you have the following expansions:

$$f(x + h) = f(x) + (f'(x))(h) + \frac{(f''(x))(h^2)}{2} + \frac{(f'''(x))(h^3)}{6} + \ldots \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$f(x) = f(x) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$f(x - h) = f(x) + (f'(x))(-h) + \frac{(f''(x))((-h)^2)}{2} + \frac{(f'''(x))((-h)^3)}{6} + \ldots \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Thus, \eqref{eq1A} minus \eqref{eq2A}, and dividing by $h$, gives

$$\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(x) + \frac{(f''(x))(h)}{2} + \frac{(f'''(x))(h^2)}{6} + \ldots \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

and \eqref{eq1A} minus \eqref{eq3A}, and dividing by $2h$, gives

$$\frac{f(x + h) - f(x - h)}{2h} = f'(x) + \frac{(f'''(x))(h^2)}{6} + \ldots \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Since $h^2 = (-h)^2$, the $f''(x)$ terms cancel, so there's no $h$ term compared to \eqref{eq4A}.

Thus, the lowest order in terms of powers of $h$ error terms for computing $f'(x)$ in \eqref{eq4A} has a power of $1$, i.e., it's $O(h)$, while in \eqref{eq5A} it has a power of $2$, i.e., it's $O(h^2)$.

Comment: oh thanks for your answer, but could you give a layman explanation of why the second expression is "better"?

Comment: And what does the $O(h)$ means here? and how is it being used here?

Comment: @john_w Let $f'(x)$ be the actual derivative & $f'_e(x,h)$ be the estimate for a given $h$. As [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) explains, $f'_e(x,h)$ being $O(h)$ means as $h \to 0$ there's a constant $C$ such that $|f'(x) - f'_e(x,h)| \le Ch$. In layman's terms, it means the error is around a fixed multiple of $h$. As $h \to 0$, note $h$ decreases slower than $h^2$, $h^3$, etc., e.g., $h=.1$ gives $h^2=0.01$, $h^3=0.001$, etc., while $h=0.001$ gives $h^2=0.00001$, $h^3=0.0000001$, etc. Thus, relative to each other, the term with lowest power of $h$ will ...

Comment: @john_w (cont.) dominate as $h \to 0$. This is the basis for why the lowest power of $h$ becomes the value of the order, e.g. $O(h)$ for the first one use $f(x)$ and $O(h^2)$ for the second one using $f(x - h)$. As for the second expression is "better", consider the constant $C$ mentioned earlier being about the same in both cases (even if they're somewhat different, as $h$ becomes smaller & smaller, that difference becomes relatively less & less important). Thus, if $h = 0.1$, the first error would be about $0.1C$ while the second one would be about $0.01C$ instead, i.e., only $0.1$. ...

Comment: @john_w If, instead, $h = 0.001$, the first error is now only $0.001C$, but the second error is much smaller, at about $0.00001C$, i.e., about $0.001$ of the other error. Obviously, the ratio is $h$, so as $h \to 0$, the relative errors go to $0$, i.e., the second error keeps getting closer, relatively speaking, to the actual derivative compared to the first error. I hope this helps you understand a bit better about big O notation (i.e., order of), and how it works when estimating the derivative. If not, you may wish to ask a new question about specifically what you don't understand.